# MyBatis cannot find mybatis-config.xml

Tags: java, mybatis

I'm some trouble getting MyBatis (3.4.6) working.

I have placed my **mybatis-config.xml** file in the **src/main/resources** folder of my project but when I run a unit test I get the following error.

```
> java.io.IOException: Could not find resource mybatis-config.xml   at
> org.apache.ibatis.io.Resources.getResourceAsStream(Resources.java:114)
```

This is the code I am using to read the XML file.

```
String resource = "mybatis-config.xml";
try 
{
    InputStream inputStream = Resources.getResourceAsStream(resource);
    sqlSessionFactory = new SqlSessionFactoryBuilder().build(inputStream);

} catch (IOException ex) {

    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

Anyone got any ideas?

Comment: How do you run unit tests? Do you use IDE or do you use maven or gradle? If you use IDE is your project correctly setup namely is `src/main/resources` configured as a source folder?

Comment: Yeah I run the unit tests from eclipse IDE & src/main/resources has been added as a source folder.

Comment: Then you need to provide minimal verifiable example that demonstrates the problem. This [minimal example](https://bitbucket.org/rkonoval/mybatis-simple/src/master/) works just fine when I import it to eclipse and run the test. Try to remove things gradually from your project to get the minimal thing that still does not work and compare it will my example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the input folks, I figured out what was wrong.

It was the weirdest Eclipse config issue I have seen in 15 years of programming, somehow all the XML files in the project were marked as TEXT files.

Think it might be time to move to IntelliJ.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on what your `Resources` class is doing. Maybe try with "/mybatis-config.xml" ( note the leading slash ).

Comment: This is mybatis class and it uses another class that [appends](https://github.com/mybatis/mybatis-3/blob/master/src/main/java/org/apache/ibatis/io/ClassLoaderWrapper.java#L151) '/' in case it failed to load the resource with the provided name.

Comment: Looks like a classpath problem. You might want to just use `getClass().getResourceAsStream(..)` to make sure that everything is all right. Also, double-check that the `src/main/resources` folder is actually on the classpath.

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is an old question but for those who stumble on this I'd place that config.xml file under src/test/resources in addition to the one for regular code. You might want a different test configuration.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `SQLMapClient` for reading the SqlConfig file.

```
private static String path= "/sqlmap-config.xml";

public static SqlMapClient getSqlMapInstance() throws IOException {
        Reader reader = Resources.getResourceAsReader(path);
        sqlMapClient = SqlMapClientBuilder.buildSqlMapClient(reader);

        return sqlMapClient;

    }
```

make sure your `sqlmap-config.xml` is located in classpath `resoures` folder.

Answer (score 0):

If you use IDEA, you could try mark resources folder as root resources file so that the xml file could be found by program.

Comment: The OP is looking for code based solutions. Im not sure how this aligns to his query